# Optimal coverage of arbitrary mask by strided masks

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, combinatorics

Say we have bit mask with some bits on and off:

```
1001110010101
```

We want to "deduce pattern", by covering this mask with as few strided masks as possible.

By "strided mask" I mean masks like:

```
11111111....
01010101....
00100100....
```

We can choose any length of strided masks and we need to cover initial mask completely.

Say for

```
1001110010101
```

Answer might be 3:

```
1001110010101
1001
    11
        10101
```

But I am not sure even in this case -- may be we can do better?

More tricky example:

```
11011101
```

covered by only 2 strided masks:

```
01010101
10001
```

Naive solution is 3: 11, 111 and 1

I have feeling this problem may be well-known, something like regular Post Embedding or like Set Cover, but everything I know is not exactly this problem.

How do you think can we have good algorithm here or can we prove NP or even undecidability?

Comment: Probably an important detail: May the masks overlap?

Comment: @user253751 lets say, we allow any element to be "used" only once.

Comment: Your problem is clearly in NP, as you demonstrated in your post, and so it can't be undecidable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is known as *(exact) cover by arithmetic progressions* (depending on whether you allow overlaps or not). Both variants were shown to be NP-complete by Heath, [Covering a Set with Arithmetic Progressions is NP-Complete](https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/19566/TR-89-25.pdf).

Comment: Indeed, I didn't remember about X3C. Thanks!